# What is the best way to copy a list?

Tags: python

What is the best way to copy a list? I know the following ways, which one is better? Or is there another way?

```
lst = ['one', 2, 3]

lst1 = list(lst)

lst2 = lst[:]

import copy
lst3 = copy.copy(lst)
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you want a shallow copy (elements aren't copied) use:

```
lst2=lst1[:]
```

If you want to make a deep copy then use the copy module:

```
import copy
lst2=copy.deepcopy(lst1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by elements aren't copied?

Comment: If the elements are mutable objects they are passed by reference, you have to use deepcopy to really copy them.

Comment: It will only copy references that are held by the list.  If an element in the list holds a reference to another object, that won't be copied.  9 times out of 10 you just need the shallow copy.

Comment: @sheats see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy

Comment: note: made the mistake of confusing lst2=lst1 as a shallow copy, it's just a ref.

Comment: A clearer approach would be: `lst2 = list (lst1)`

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ of all the mentioned methods including the one mentioned by you which is the best, I mean in terms of optimization of code..

Comment: I am quite comfortable with the syntax of the first approach, and it's a little dogmatic, but I think it's a little clearer / more explicit to do, rather than `list2 = list1[:]`, instead: `list2 = list1.copy()`

Answer (score 24):

I often use:

```
lst2 = lst1 * 1
```

If lst1 it contains other containers (like other lists) you should use deepcopy from the copy lib as shown by Mark.

---

UPDATE: Explaining deepcopy

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> b = a*1
>>> a,b
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[2] = 55 
>>> a,b
([0, 1, 55, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

As you may see only a changed...
I'll try now with a list of lists

```
>>> 
>>> a = [range(i,i+3) for i in range(3)]
>>> a
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
>>> b = a*1
>>> a,b
([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]], [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
```

Not so readable, let me print it with a for:

```
>>> for i in (a,b): print i   
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
>>> a[1].append('appended')
>>> for i in (a,b): print i

[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 'appended'], [2, 3, 4]]
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 'appended'], [2, 3, 4]]
```

You see that? It appended to the b[1] too, so b[1] and a[1] are the very same object.
Now try it with deepcopy

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> b = deepcopy(a)
>>> a[0].append('again...')
>>> for i in (a,b): print i

[[0, 1, 2, 'again...'], [1, 2, 3, 'appended'], [2, 3, 4]]
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 'appended'], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: `copy()` will not work in the last case, you need `deepcopy()` whenever you have a reference inside the object.

Comment: I thought that your trick of using `lst1*1` was really nice...but, sadly, rough profiling suggests that it is at least twice as slow as `lst1[:]`, which is slightly faster than `copy(last1)`.

Answer (score 14):

You can also do:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list(a)
```

Comment: Is the result a shallow or deep copy?

Comment: No, using list() is definitely a shallow copy. Try it out.

Comment: Is there a speed difference? Arguably when you do `[:]`, the library is smart enough to know that a copy is being made and thus it could potentially invoke some native C code to do so. With `list(iterable)` does it know/care that the iterable is already materialized and thus can be copied efficiently?

Comment: So, is the only way to get a deepcopy of a list by using the copy module? Seems strange that Python doesn't include deep copy in its standard functionality.

Answer (score 7):

I like to do:

```
lst2 = list(lst1)
```

The advantage over lst1[:] is that the same idiom works for dicts:

```
dct2 = dict(dct1)
```

Comment: There was actually a pretty long discussion about the dictionary copy versus list copy on the Python 3K mailing list:
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-February/thread.html#12052

Comment: The bit of info here is that for dictionaries, you can do d = d.copy()

Answer (score 3):

Short lists, [:] is the best:

```
In [1]: l = range(10)

In [2]: %timeit list(l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 477 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit l[:]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 236 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit copy(l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 us per loop
```

For larger lists, they're all about the same:

```
In [7]: l = range(50000)

In [8]: %timeit list(l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 261 us per loop

In [9]: %timeit l[:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 261 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit copy(l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 248 us per loop
```

For very large lists (I tried 50MM), they're still about the same.

Comment: I wouldn't bother if I have to do a single copy in between 100s of lines of code. Only if it is a core part of the application and list copy is frequent, I might bother.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
import copy
list2 = copy.copy(list1)
```

This should do the same thing as Mark Roddy's shallow copy.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance, there is some overhead to calling `list()` versus slicing.  So for short lists, `lst2 = lst1[:]` is about twice as fast as `lst2 = list(lst1)`.

In most cases, this is probably outweighed by the fact that `list()` is more readable, but in tight loops this can be a valuable optimization.