# How to make a copy of a list of objects not change when modifying the original list?

Tags: python, list, object

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to clone a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python)
>   [What is the best way to copy a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184643/what-is-the-best-way-to-copy-a-list-in-python)

```
original_list = [Object1(), Object2(), Object3()]
copy_list = original_list
original_list.pop()
```

If I remove an object from the original list, how can I keep the copy list from changing as well?

Original List

```
[<Object.Object instance at 0x00EA29E0>, <Object.Object instance at 0x00EA2DC8>, <Object.Object instance at 0x00EA2EE0>]
```

Copy List after popping the original list (I want this to equal what is above)

```
[<Object.Object instance at 0x00EA29E0>, <Object.Object instance at 0x00EA2DC8>]
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [copy.deepcopy()](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for a deep copy:

```
import copy
copy_list = copy.deepcopy(original_list)
```

For a shallow copy use [copy.copy()](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.copy):

```
import copy
copy_list = copy.copy(original_list)
```

or slice with no endpoints specified :

```
copy_list = original_list[:]
```

See the [copy docs](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) for an explanation about deep & shallow copies.

Comment: `copy.copy()` is actually shallow copy, `copy.deepcopy()` is deep copy

Comment: @Paul Woolcock:  Thanks for the catch.  I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Let it be noted that the slice is also a shallow copy, as this was not explicitly said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068714/3249197

Answer (score 8):

This will work.

```
import copy
copy_list = copy.copy(original_list)
```

Also

```
copy_list = list(original_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy)

> Return a deep copy of x.

```
from copy import deepcopy

original_list = [Object1(), Object2(), Object3()]
copy_list = deepcopy(original_list)
original_list.pop()
```

But note that slicing will work faster in your case:

```
copy_list = original_list[:]
```