# Does a slicing operation give me a deep or shallow copy?

Tags: python, list, copy, deep-copy

The [official Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) say that using the slicing operator and assigning in Python makes a shallow copy of the sliced list.

But when I write code for example:

```
o = [1, 2, 4, 5]
p = o[:]
```

And when I write:

```
id(o)
id(p)
```

I get different id's and also appending one one list does not reflect in the other list. Isn't it creating a deep copy or is there somewhere I am going wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are creating a *shallow* copy, because nested values are not copied, merely referenced. A *deep* copy would create copies of the values referenced by the list too.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [{}]
>>> lst_copy = lst[:]
>>> lst_copy[0]['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> lst_copy.append(42)
>>> lst
[{'foo': 'bar'}]
>>> id(lst) == id(lst_copy)
False
>>> id(lst[0]) == id(lst_copy[0])
True
```

Here the *nested* dictionary is not copied; it is merely referenced by both lists. The new element `42` is not shared.

Remember that everything in Python is an object, and names and list elements are merely references to those objects. A copy of a list creates a new outer list, but the new list merely receives references to the *exact same objects*.

A proper deep copy creates new copies of each and every object contained in the list, recursively:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> lst_deepcopy = deepcopy(lst)
>>> id(lst_deepcopy[0]) == id(lst[0])
False
```

Comment: Then why is it I am getting different ids

Comment: @user2528042: Because the *outer list objects* are not the same.

Comment: @user2528042 Because the original list *is copied* to a new object. Just all elements within are not copied, so if the list contains a mutable object (ints are not mutable) changing that object will change it in both the original and the copied list because both have a copy of the reference to the same object.

Comment: @user2528042: that it's a shallow copy doesn't mean that `id(o) == id(p)`, it means that `[id(x) for x in o] == [id(x) for x in p]`.  See the difference?

Comment: Is the effective difference only important for nested types and in-place list modifying methods like `append()` ? i.e. Instead of your example `lst_copy[0]['foo'] = 'bar'` if your type is `List[int]` and you do `>>>lst_copy[0] = 42 ... >>> list` you don't see 42 in the original list.

Comment: @Davos: `lst_copy[0]['foo'] = 'bar'` doesn't alter `list_copy`, it only alters the dictionary object referenced by `lst_copy[0]`. In Python [everything is basically a reference](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), including list indices. A shallow copy of a list creates copies of the references, and does not follow the references to make copies of the referenced objects.

Answer (score 8):

You should know that tests using `is` or `id` can be misleading of whether a true copy is being made with immutable and [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) objects such as strings, integers and tuples that contain immutables.

Consider an easily understood example of interned strings:

```
>>> l1=['one']
>>> l2=['one']
>>> l1 is l2
False
>>> l1[0] is l2[0]
True
```

Now make a shallow copy of `l1` and test the immutable string:

```
>>> l3=l1[:]
>>> l3 is l1
False
>>> l3[0] is l1[0]
True
```

Now make a copy of the string contained by `l1[0]`:

```
>>> s1=l1[0][:]
>>> s1
'one'
>>> s1 is l1[0] is l2[0] is l3[0]
True               # they are all the same object
```

Try a deepcopy where every element should be copied:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> l4=deepcopy(l1)
>>> l4[0] is l1[0]
True
```

In each case, the string `'one'` is being interned into Python's internal cache of immutable strings and `is` will show that they are the same (they have the same `id`). It is implementation and version dependent of what gets interned and when it does, so you cannot depend on it. It can be a substantial memory and performance enhancement.

You can force an example that does not get interned instantly:

```
>>> s2=''.join(c for c in 'one')
>>> s2==l1[0]
True
>>> s2 is l1[0]
False
```

And then you can use the Python [intern function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) to cause that string to refer to the cached object if found:

```
>>> l1[0] is s2
False
>>> s2=intern(s2)
>>> l1[0] is s2
True
```

Same applies to tuples of immutables:

```
>>> t1=('one','two')
>>> t2=t1[:]
>>> t1 is t2
True
>>> t3=deepcopy(t1)
>>> t3 is t2 is t1
True
```

And mutable lists of immutables (like integers) can have the list members interred:

```
>>> li1=[1,2,3]
>>> li2=deepcopy(li1)
>>> li2 == li1
True
>>> li2 is li1
False
>>> li1[0] is li2[0]
True
```

So you may use python operations that you KNOW will copy something but the end result is another reference to an interned immutable object. The `is` test is only a dispositive test of a copy being made IF the items are mutable.

Comment: On Python 3, `intern` has been moved to the `sys` module, so you need to do `import sys; s=sys.intern(s)`