# Issue in using index with Slicing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7.6 and tried following code,

```
mylist1=["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7"]
print mylist1 #prints ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7']
mylist1[2:5]=["B3","B4","B5"]
print mylist1 #prints ['A1', 'A2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'A6', 'A7']
print mylist1[2:3][0] #prints B3
mylist1[2:5][0]="C5"
print mylist1 #prints ['A1', 'A2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B4', 'A6', 'A7']
```

I am able to modify list `mylist1` using `mylist1[2:5]=["B3","B4","B5"]`

But Why statement `mylist1[2:5][0]="C5"` not changing list `mylist1` ?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155951/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-assignment-that-slices-the-whole-list-and-d

Answer (score 0):

Because slicing creates a shallow copy of your original list. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068714/1388292) for more details about shallow and deep copy.
In simple terms, when you do

```
mylist1[2:5][0]="C5"
```

the interpreter creates a new `list` object with the 3rd, 4th and 5th element of `mylist1`. Then it assigns the string `"C5"` to its first element and because there is no reference to the new list object just created, it gets garbage-collected, leaving the original `mylist1` intact.