# Is python making a copy of my array in "for elem in A[a:b]"?

Tags: python

When I do something like

```
for elem in A[a:b]:
  something(elem)
```

what is happening? Does python make a copy of my array somewhere in memory, or does it just start and end at the selected positions? Is this the same, in terms of memory usage, as using `range()` as in the following example?

```
for i in range(a,b):
  something(A[i])
```

Comment: slicing a sequence returns a copy of it - in fact, writing `seq[:]` is a quick-and-dirty way of copying a sequence.

Comment: If `A` is a list then `A[a:b]` is creating a new list containing the specified slice of `A`. It is not the same as using a range.

Comment: So it is a better idea to use `range()` in this case ?

Comment: @arthll define "better" - processing speed? Memory usage? Code tidyness?

Comment: What happens when you do a slice is subject of the object you are slicing. Most standard sequence types create a shallow copy, meaning the new sequence is detached from the old sequence but the contained items are references to the same objects as before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a slicing operation give me a deep or shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068707/does-a-slicing-operation-give-me-a-deep-or-shallow-copy) TL;DR yes it makes a copy of the list

Comment: Just to make sure, when you say "array", you mean [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), right? Arrays are different, like [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) or [NumPy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html).

Comment: @wjandrea I said array thinking about lists and tuples.

Comment: @wjandrea Regarding the question you suggested. It helped me understand the slicing better, thank you. But when I posted the question I was wondering if placing it in the `for` argument would change anything. But as I understand it, it makes a copy, but it actually points to the address of the items in the original list, so it's not like I'm going to make a completely new list.

Comment: @arthll It is a completely new list. Lists don't actually contain their objects, just references to them. And to be clear, the `for` context doesn't change anything. And you're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **depends on the type** of the given object you refer to as "array". If you meant the built-in type `list` -- yes, a copy is made:

```
>>> a = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> a
['X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> b = a[0:2]
>>> b
['X', 'Y']
>>> a[0] = 42  # we modify `a`
>>> a
[42, 'Y', 'Z']
>>> b          # `b` did not change
['X', 'Y']
```

The same applies to many other sequence types; for example, to `bytearray`:

```
>>> ar = bytearray(b'XYZ')
>>> ar
bytearray(b'XYZ')
>>> ar2 = ar[0:2]
>>> ar2
bytearray(b'XY')
>>> ar[0] = 32  # we modify `a`
>>> ar
bytearray(b' YZ')
>>> ar2         # `ar2` did not change
bytearray(b'XY')
```

But there are types for whom it is not the case; for example:

```
>>> ar = bytearray(b'XYZ')
>>> view = memoryview(ar)
>>> view
<memory at 0x...>
>>> view.tobytes()
b'XYZ'
>>> view2 = view[0:2]
>>> view2
<memory at 0x...>
>>> view2.tobytes()
b'XY'
>>> view[0] = 32  # this statement modifies both `view` and `view2`, and also `ar`!
>>> view.tobytes()
b' YZ'
>>> view2.tobytes()
b' Y'
>>> ar
bytearray(b' YZ')
```

> Is this the same, in terms of memory usage, as using range() as in the following example?

`range()` (or, in Python 2, `xrange()`) is another story, as it does not store its items, but only the *range limits* (i.e., *start* and *stop*) and the optional *step*:

```
>>> range(1, 14, 2)  # items 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 are not stored in memory
range(1, 14, 2)
>>> range(1000000000000000000000)  # it does not take zillion bytes of memory :-)
range(0, 1000000000000000000000)
```