# Syntax for returning the entire list when using the minus sign?

Tags: python

Python lists have nifty indexing/slicing capabilities. Here are several examples:

```
x = "123456"

x[:-3]
'123'

x[:-1]
'12345'  # -1 slices off last element

x[:-0]  # -0 slices off .. everything .. this is what i'd like to fix
''
```

I would like to slice off a variable number of elements `d`:

```
x[:-d]
```

But if `d` were 0 we get a much different result than desired.  A workaround is:

```
d = 0
x[:-d if d else len(x)]
'123456'
```

That is possible - but is there any [shorter] alternative?

Comment: Only a little bit shorter: `x[:-d] if d else x`

Comment: `x[:-d or None]`

Comment: To be clear, `-0` is `0`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny  nice one! pls make that an answer

Comment: @WestCoastProjects - It might be shorter, but creates an unnecessary full copy. JANO's comment is a better solution.

Comment: slicing *always* creates a copy?  I just looked up and it seems a new `list` object were created but the contents remain the same. i'm still digesting it .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19070318/1056563

Comment: When slicing a `list`: always. `list[:]` creates a full shallow copy.

Comment: CPython, at least, appears to recognize then when entire string is being returned and does not make a copy. `x is x[:None]` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @chepner Tuples probably, too?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects That's only because you didn't actually test it with a list. With a list, it does create a copy.

Comment: Also, that solution has been posted already.

Comment: @KellyBundy  Ur right i tested with a string. I continually find the treatment of string's as pseudo-lists in python as a confusion

Comment: Well, if you find it confusing, then stop doing it :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy  no choice on that: a string is sort of a list like it or not.

Comment: @KellyBundy In general, it's easy enough for `__getitem__` to check if the `slice` items it receives corresponds to an exact copy, so I suspect any immutable value would be optimized to return itself.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Not in Python terminology. If you're looking for the common generic term, it's "sequence".

Comment: OK I'll buy "sequence".  I know the java and scala interfaces / class hierarchies v well but do not in python

Comment: @WestCoastProjects You can btw find those terms in the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) and the [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `None`, which is the default for missing start/stop/step values:

```
x[:-d or None]
```

Comment: This is an attractive solution and upvoting but given it does create a new shallow list  - which is something i had not considered - another answer will be awarded

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Sometimes creating a copy and sometimes not is inconsistent and dangerous.

Comment: Actually it does *not* create a new list so this is a good answer  `x[: -d or None] is x` `True`

Comment: @WestCoastProjects - I didn't know about this exception/optimization for strings. It's been discussed on the python developer mailing list in [2008](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-May/079691.html) citing a discussion in 2006 (which is way above my head).

Comment: Comparing benchmarks for `x[:-d] if d else x` vs `x[:-d or None]` with `d=0`, it turns out that the first one is ~2.7x faster. My guess is that a new string **is** created but the memory location of the old string is reused because of string interning. [Copying a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804453/how-can-i-copy-a-python-string) is much harder than I thought.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Nah, I think it's just because the first one only needs to load `d`, check its truth value, and load `x`, while the second one has some additional steps. Look for `unicode_result_unchanged` in the source code.

Comment: @KellyBundy - You are correct: [checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f03d318ca42578e45405717aedd4ac26ea52aaed/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L14470) for the special case of a full slice and [returns the unicode string](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f03d318ca42578e45405717aedd4ac26ea52aaed/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L711)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I wasn't sure whether it's there in `unicode_subscript` or [in `PyUnicode_Substring`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f03d318ca42578e45405717aedd4ac26ea52aaed/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12759-L12760), but I think you're right (now that I looked for uses of the latter).

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're hitting is that `-0` is the same as `0`, and `x[0:0]` is an empty slice.

I'd suggest:

```
x[:len(x)-d]
```

Comment: I like the aesthetics of the Kelly Bundy answer a tiny bit more but this one avoids creating a new shallow list so awarding

Comment: @WestCoastProjects This creates a new one as well, you're not making sense.

Comment: @KellyBundy ur right, it was a different answer that avoided the new list `x[:-d] if d else x`   i will update