# Python - Why this list doesn't change

Tags: python, list, function

I want to change a part of a list and save the result.
I would like to know why this method is not working.
And Thank you!

###### Code:

```
def Test(L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        L[i] = L[i][1:]

L = ["-stackoverflow", "-Python", "-C++"]
Test(L[1:])
print(L)
```

###### Ouput:

['-stackoverflow', '-Python', '-C++']

###### Expected:

['-stackoverflow', 'Python', 'C++']

Comment: your function needs to return the modified list and reassign it at the caller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a slicing operation give me a deep or shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068707/does-a-slicing-operation-give-me-a-deep-or-shallow-copy)

Answer (score 1):

You call the `Test()` function with `L[1:]`, but this is only a copy of the list and not the original `L` list. So when you modify the list in your function, you modify the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `[:]` on a list, it constructs a new list.  When you called `Test(L[1:])`, you didn't pass it `L` but rather a completely new List unrelated to `L`. There are two things you can do here: Either return the new list for reassignment or pass `L` into `Test()` and not `L[1:]`.

Comment: *"a completely new List unrelated to L"* - no exactly: the strings are still the same instances. If OP would mutate `L[i]` instead of assign to it then it would work.

Comment: @luk2302, you can't mutate strings.  It is the list itself the the OP wants to change.

Answer (score 1):

your function needs to return the modified list and reassign it at the caller.

```
def Test(L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        L[i] = L[i][1:]
    return L

L = ["-stackoverflow", "-Python", "-C++"]
L = Test(L[1:])
print(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to write `Test(L)` and not `Test(L[1:])` as the function is already doing the operation for you.

```
 def Test(L):
   for i in range(len(L)):
     L[i] = L[i][1:]

L = ["-stackoverflow", "-Python", "-C++"]

Test(L)
print(L)
```