# Why does my original list change?

Tags: python, list, function

I a wrote a function SwapCities that is able to swap entries 3 and 4 in a list.

So f.e. [0,1,2,3,4] should become [0,1,2,4,3]. This function works perfectly, but strangely my original list also changes which I do not want.

This is my code:

```
def SwapCities(solution):
    n = 3##randint(0,NumberOfCities-1)
    m = 4##randint(0,NumberOfCities-1)
    result = solution
    temp1 = solution[n]
    temp2 = solution[m]
    result[n] = temp2
    result[m] = temp1
    return result
```

---

```
print "Start"
IncumbentSolution = list(x for x in range(0,NumberOfCities))
print IncumbentSolution

print "After swap" NewSolution = SwapCities(IncumbentSolution)
print NewSolution

print "Original solution"
print IncumbentSolution
```

I get the following result:

```
How many cities?
8 Start [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
After swap [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7]
Original solution [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7]   (why did this change?!)
```

As you can see my original solution changed which it should not do.

I have no clue why this happens. Even when I change the code such that the changes to are applied to a copy of the original list I get this result. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
IncumbentSolution = list(x for x in range(0,NumberOfCities))
print "Start"
print IncumbentSolution

print "After swap"
tmpsolution = IncumbentSolution
NewSolution = SwapCities(tmpsolution)
print NewSolution

print "Original solution"
print IncumbentSolution
```

Comment: About copying lists: http://stackoverflow.com/a/184660/577423

Comment: It's worth noting you don't need temporary variables to do a swap in Python - `solution[n], solution[m] = solution[m], solution[n]`. This is shorter, more readable and also more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

`SwapCities` is *mutating* the contents of `solution`.
Since `solution` points to the same list as `IncumbentSolution`, the values inside `IncumbentSolution` are altered too.

---

To preserve the original values in `IncumbentSolution`, make a new copy of the list:

```
tmpsolution = list(IncumbentSolution)
```

makes a shallow copy of the the original list. Since the contents of `IncumbentSolution` are immutable numbers, a shallow copy suffices. If the contents included, say, `dicts` which were also being mutated, then you would need to make a deep copy of the list:

```
import copy
tmpsolution = copy.deepcopy(IncumbentSolution)
```

Comment: I'd always recommend using `list(IncumbentSolution)`. It does the same job, but is more readable. `[:]` is generally confusing to new Python users (see how many questions there are about it on SO alone), and while that isn't always a good reason not to use something, it is when we have a much better replacement at hand.

Comment: @Lattyware: Good idea. It is confusing to use `arr[:]` especially when using `NumPy` since there it returns a view, not a copy.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you modified the list inside the function.

By passing the list to the function you simply created another reference to the same object,
`solution` and  `IncumbentSolution` actually point to the same list object.

You should pass a shallow copy to the function, using `IncumbentSolution[:]`.

```
>>> def func(x):
...     return id(x)
... 
>>> lis = range(5)
>>> id(lis),func(lis)     #both `x` and `lis` point to the same object
(163001004, 163001004)

>>> id(lis),func(lis[:])  #pass a shallow copy, `lis[:]` or `list(lis)`
(163001004, 161089068)
```