# Why does Python modify the list which is out of the loop?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

for this list:

```
current_trace = [[3,5,1,5,7,9,4]]
```

I run the `sliding_tristep()` method, which includes the `predict()` and `window()` methods:

```
def predict(lst):
    print "predicting for", lst
    print "result", max(lst) + 0.0
    return max(lst) + 0.0

def window(lst, n=3):
    for x in range(1, len(lst)+1): # or len(l)+n to continue till the end
        yield(lst[max(0, x-n):x])

def sliding_tristep(full_trace, future_step = 2, window_size = 3):

    for user_trace in full_trace:
        for current_input in window(user_trace):
            counter = 0
            trace = current_input
            accumulator = []
            while counter <= future_step:
                next_prediction = predict(trace)  
                trace.append(next_prediction)
                accumulator.append(next_prediction)
                trace = trace[-window_size:]
                counter += 1

            print current_input, accumulator
```

When I run `sliding_tristep(current_trace)`, in the output for the `print current_input, accumulator` line I notice that the `current_input` has been modified although it is out of the while loop which makes the calculations in `sliding_tristep(current_trace)`.

I wonder why does this happen? How is that possible for python to modify a list which is not used at all in the subsequent loop.

Comment: `trace = current_input` does not "copy" the list, `trace.append()` is equivalent to `current_input.append()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I run `sliding_tristep(current_trace)`, in the output for the `print current_input, accumulator` line I notice that the `current_trace` has been modified

just tested your code:

```
>>> current_trace = [[3,5,1,5,7,9,4]]
>>> sliding_tristep(current_trace)
...
>>> current_trace
[[3, 5, 1, 5, 7, 9, 4]]
```

`current_trace` does *not* get modified.

> I wonder why does this happen? How is that possible for python to modify a list which is not used at all in the subsequent loop.

Though, I guess you meant `current_input` and not `current_trace`.

`current_input` gets modified, because `trace` is a reference to `current_input` and trace gets modified.

If you want to make a copy of `current_input` as `trace`, here's one way to do it:

```
>>> foo = [1,2,3]
>>> bar = foo[:]
>>> bar.append(4)
>>> foo
[1, 2, 3]
>>> bar
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

applied to your code:

```
def sliding_tristep(full_trace, future_step = 2, window_size = 3):
    for user_trace in full_trace:
        for current_input in window(user_trace):
            counter = 0
            trace = current_input[:] # make a copy of current_input
            accumulator = []
            while counter <= future_step:
                next_prediction = predict(trace)  
                trace.append(next_prediction)
                accumulator.append(next_prediction)
                trace = trace[-window_size:]
                counter += 1                    
            print current_input, accumulator
```

If you don't modify the elements of the list (and as integers are non-mutable, you can't), you can do the shallow copy as I'm suggesting you in the aforementioned example. If you're using mutable objects (`lists` or other kind of objects), then you want to do a deep copy using the `copy` module. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/184660/1290438 on this topic.

Comment: Parameter passing is independent of mutability. Passing an immutable object also gives the function a "reference".

Comment: it's independant, but it's two conditions that are enough for making a mistake. Anyway, I had a better and more thorough look into his code, and tried to understand what he *meant* behind what he *says*.

Comment: yes you are right, I meant `current_input` instead of `current_trace`.

Answer (score 0):

using `trace.extend(current_input)` , instead of `trace = current_input` solves the problem. although, a `trace` list has to be initialized beforehand.

The solution would look like:

```
def sliding_tristep(full_trace, future_step = 2, window_size = 3):

    for user_trace in full_trace:
        for current_input in window(user_trace): 
            counter = 0
            trace = [] #here is the solution
            trace.extend(current_input) #here is the solution
            accumulator = []
            while counter <= future_step:
                next_prediction = predict(trace)  
                trace.append(next_prediction)
                accumulator.append(next_prediction)
                trace = trace[-window_size:]
                counter += 1
```

Comment: well, you don't need to do an empty list and copy the content of the other list in two steps, you can do it in one step using `trace = current_input[:]` as I tell you in my answer. Also, do not comment on your question using an answer, but update your question or make a comment!

Comment: @zmo: the person who asked a question can most definitely leave an answer to indicate how he solved the problem; provided the specific solution isn't already mentioned. You cannot update your question with the solution, that would defeat the entire purpose of having a separate answer section.

Comment: well, true for not updating the question, but what he says can definitely fit in a comment. And btw, the solution has already been given in my answer, and the cause of his problem exposed in a comment. Basically, the OP answering himself is just non-sense.