# adding list value into dictionary after appending new value into list during each iteration

Tags: python

This is my program to append list value into dictionary

```
lis=['a','b','c']
st=['d','e']
count=0

f={}
for s in st:
    lis.append(s) 
    f[count]=lis
    count+=1
    print f
```

my expected output is

```
{0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

but i got

```
{0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

as  output. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any pattern .. to get result

Comment: No. I need output like this {0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}

Comment: what is `a` in `f[count]=a`?

Comment: `f[count] = lis + [s]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `copy` the list, because if you add it to the dictionary then modify it, it will change all the copies that exist in the dictionary.

```
import copy
l = ['a','b','c']
st = ['d','e']
count = 0
f = {}
for s in st:
    l.append(s)
    f[count] = copy.copy(l)
    count += 1
    print f
```

Output

```
{0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
{0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

Comment: you don't really need to deepcopy because the elements of the list are not references to objects. You just need to copy the list.

Comment: why not use `f[count]=lis[:]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that would work just as well, and would save the import of the `copy` module. I guess I was just trying to make it very clear to the OP that they indeed need a copy of the list because they don't want all the keys to point to the same list as their values.

Answer (score 0):

```
lis=['a','b','c']
st=['d','e']    
{ i :lis+st[:i+1] for i in range(0,2) }
#output ={0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you expand it by adding some text to explain how it works / how it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the list before putting in `f` so that it's value doesn't change as you add elements to the original list:

```
f[count]= lis[:]           # copy lis
```

and you get:

```
{0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
{0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

**Note:** Thanks to @PadraicCunningham for pointing out that `[:]` notation is faster than `list()` -- at least for small list (see [What is the best way to copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184643/1290264) or [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/1290264)).

Comment: using `f[count]=lis[:]` is a lot more effcient

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you give a reference?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, I found a reference. Still, post another if you have a better one in mind.

Comment: For very small lists it's the overhead related to function call that makes it slower(even a call to empty function takes some nano seconds), otherwise is slightly faster than slicing. But slicing should be preferred, because many time people use list as a variable name. (Python 2)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I hope `l` is your case is not `range(100)`. Because `range()`'s slicing will take constant time in Python 3.