# Bug where copy of a list is being modified through the old one

Tags: python, list, debugging

I was working with matrices in python, and after hours spent trying to debug a program, managed to trace the problem to essentially this code, where all non-zero entries of a matrix are uniformly increased.

```
list2=[[1,2],[0,4]]
list1=list2
for row in list1:
    for i in range(0,len(row)):
        if row[i]!=0:
            row[i]=row[i]+10
print(list1) #returns [[11,12],[0,14]], as expected
print(list2) #returns [[11,12],[0,14]], want to return [[1,2],[0,4]]
```

There's something fundamental I'm missing here. I thought by declaring `list1=list2` a new list was created, which the rest of the code modified while keeping `list2` unaltered.

What's the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: from copy import deepcopy; list1=deepcopy(list2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutable vs mutable types - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
list2=[[1,2],[0,4]]
list1=list2
```

does *not* create a new list in `list1`, it simply binds the name `list1` to the same object as `list2`. Therefore any changes made to the list via name `list2` will also be visible via `list1`.

You could use the [**`copy`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#module-copy) module:

```
import copy
list2 = [[1,2],[0,4]]
list1 = copy.deepcopy(list2)
```

`list1` will now refer to a copy of `list2` and changes to the list will be reflected only via `list2`.

For lists containing more complicated objects such as other lists, `copy.deepcopy()` will make recursive copies of the nested objects.

Comment: I just tried that change, but it still returns `[[11,12],[0,14]]` for both.

Comment: `list1 = list2[:]` is a shallow copy

Comment: Awesome, I would have never picked up on this. A whole course on python at uni, and not at any stage was this mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

#### The Problem; You are not copying the actual list

By doing `list1 = list2` you are merely copying the *handle* to the list that `list1` is referring to, in order to provide an actual copy you must say that this is what you want — explicitly.

<sub>**Example**</sub>

```
a = [1,2,3];
b = a
c = list(a) # create a new list, copying the elements in `a`
d = a[:]    # equivalent to `list(a)` (with a slightly weird syntax)
```

```
a[1] = 99
c[1] = 0
```

```
print (a) # [1,99,3]
print (b) # [1,99,3]
print (c) # [1,0,3]
print (d) # [1,2,3]
```

---

#### The Solution; Copying all the way down

The problem you are experienced will show up in an additional place since you have *lists* within a *list*. In order to make a *deep* copy all at once it is recommended to use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), as in the below example.

```
import copy
```

```
list1 = copy.deepcopy (list2)
```

**Documentation**

- [**docs.python.org** - 8.17. copy — Shallow and deep copy operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

---

#### Further reading

- [**How to clone or copy a list in Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/1090079)
- [**What is the best way to copy a list?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184643/what-is-the-best-way-to-copy-a-list)
- [**Deep copy a list in Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17873384/1090079)