# When does a variable store value and when does it store reference?

Tags: python

**Variable stores reference:**

```
a = [3, 4]
list1 = [1, 2, a]
list1[2][0]=5
print(list1)
print(a)
```

output:

[1, 2, [5, 4]]

[5, 4]

**Variable stores value:**

```
a = 3
list1 = [1, 2, a]
list1[2]=5
print(list1)
print(a)
```

output:

[1, 2, 5]

3

Is there a rule I can remember? Cause sometimes I have to manipulate the variable indirectly and I don't know if it'll change the original or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184643/what-is-the-best-way-to-copy-a-list/184660#184660, It is good to make a copy :-) when you do object assignment

Comment: I'm not sure what you think this is showing. Variables are always references.

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable always stores a reference.

The key to your confusion might be if the object that is referenced is mutable or not. In your first example `a` stores a reference to a list object which is mutable. In the second example `a` stores a reference to an immutable object of type `int`.

So this operation:

```
list1[2][0] = 5
```

modifies a reference stored in the list that `a` references to. So changes done to it are visible when you access the list via reference stored in `a`.

But this operation:

```
list1[2] = 5
```

Modifies a list element (which was initialized from the `a`) and now this element stores a reference to a new object. But a reference stored in `a` was not changed hence the result you get.

Comment: Okay, but why does `list1[2]=5` not change `a`, but `a = 5` does? Considering `list1[2]` contains `a`. Although `a` is immutable, I am assigning them to a new value, not modifying an existing one which should work either way.  

Unless, you're saying immutable types are passed as values and not references?

Comment: `list1[2]` does not contain `a`. It contains the reference to an `int` object with value  `3`. `a` also contains the reference to the same object (of type `int` and value `3`) but these two reference are stored in different locations though they  reference the same object. `list1[2]=5` modifies the value of the reference stored in `list1[2]`, this does not affect neither object of type `int` with value `3` nor the reference to it stored in `a`. Then immutable is the object of type `int` with value `3` but not the `a` (which is a variable that stores the reference to that object).

Comment: Hmmm, I see. So to achieve the same effect as the 2nd example in the 1st example. I would have to write `list1[2] = [5, 4]`. In this case, I would not be modifying the existing object pointed by both references, but pointing the reference in the list to a completely new object. And the output would be: 

`[1, 2, [5, 4]]` 

`[3, 4]`?