# how to remove a element from a list, without removing it from its copy using remove function

Tags: python

I came across this problem while using python.

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=A
B.remove(3)
print(B,A)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 4, 5] [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

when I execute this code, 3 is removed from both B and A.
I don't want A to be updated,

how can I do that?

Comment: Hey! A good source to read upon what you encounter is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment

Answer (score 1):

When you say `B=A`, the list is not copied. Instead, B just points to where the list lives in memory, just like how A does. To change A without changing B, you need to copy the list as `B=A.copy()`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to copy A to B. [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184643/what-is-the-best-way-to-copy-a-list)

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = A.copy()
B.remove(3)
print(B, A)
```